# Do modern browsers largly prevent reflected XSS attacks?

Tags: security, xss

If evildoer injects a malicious URL query string into the victim's browser address bar then that string needs to perform an HTML request in order for the server to reflect the malicious script in the query string. That script will then execute in the victim's browser. When I tried to get a really simple URL query string to perform an HTML request, no request was made. This was the query string and it didn't generate an alert:

```
localhost:\\index.html?username=<script>alert('xss just happened');</script>
```

This is a typical reflected xss attack that I've seen presented as an example. Most of the examples seem to be about 10 years old. Is the example lacking some details or are modern browsers better at repelling XSS attacks? Any pointers to background knowledge, as well as a specific explanation, would be very welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! For my money, this question could be a little bit clearer. If you're asking if a specific XSS issue is common in modern browsers, I'd call more attention to that and maybe give examples of the browsers. Otherwise, this is a bit too open-ended for the site.

Comment: @josephkibe
I hope this will make my question clearer:
1. I typed the URL in my question directly into the browser address bar and hit enter.
2. 'username' is the id of the HTML form input.
3. The php server script - which is the action attribute of the HTML form on the index page - extracts the value of the `$_GET` variable and simply echoes it back. 
4. After typing the query as per the original question and hitting enter, the query doesn't get sent to the server. So what should happen at 3 doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that XSS attack are mostly [server vulnerabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting#Server-side_versus_DOM-based_vulnerabilities), and happen if a user input is not properly sanitized. I can't tell why your example wouldn't work, but in order for the `<script>` to execute the entire username field would have to be displayed to the page as-is. Which can still happen, and generally the browser has no default protection for this (Just tried it with a php example of an XSS I had lying around). Try with a dynamic website generator ie. PHP, that takes the query string and directly displays the entire string.

There *are* standard HTTP headers in place for the prevention and mitigation of XSS attacks, notably [X-XSS-Protection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-XSS-Protection) and [Content-Security-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy), but as I understand it those are up to the website devs to implement.

It seems that XSS protection hasn't really improved, on the contrary, it has been somewhat [removed](https://www.packetlabs.net/browsers-dropping-xss-protection/) [from most browsers](https://www.zdnet.com/article/google-to-remove-chromes-built-in-xss-protection-xss-auditor/).

There's a reason that most examples you find are 10+years old, as XSS is a somewhat simple and basic vulnerability, that can be solved very well by making sure that no user input ever goes directly through the server, and must be properly sanitized.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you have a look at the 4 points of clarification that I made to commenter josephkibe above and see if they show what I might be doing wrong.  I know the server side measures needed to prevent reflected XSS but I want to understand the whole deal. 
Also, I don't understand what you mean by: 'the entire username field would have to be display to the page as-is'.
Lastly, is it possible, or likely, that my URL query string doesn't work because of security measures built into the PHP (7.2.2) engine? XSS is supposedly easy and it's driving me nuts.

Comment: You are sending the query to a .html file, which will do nothing with the query, unless you have JS in the file. You should send the query to an index.php file, that will be able to access the request and execute code. What I meant by "as-is" is that the script tag mustn't be culled or converted to HTML safe characters (such as < becoming &gt). Also I tried a XSS attack on PHP 8.x so no, PHP has no inbuilt protection.

Answer (score 0):

> `localhost:\\index.php?username=<script>alert('xss just happened');</script>`

You'll have a reflected XSS if `index.php` do not escape value from query string, for example:

```
<?php echo "Hello, ".$_GET['username']; ?>
```

> `localhost:\\index.html?username=<script>alert('xss just happened');</script>`

You'll have a reflected XSS if script in `index.html` do not escape value from query string and print it at the page, for example:

```
<script>
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  const username = urlParams.get('username');
  document.write('Hello, ' + username);
</script>
```

Above are "classic XSS" examples, those are very rare in professional code.

But there is a lot of other XSS attack vectors, because evil code can get into page via other vulns (DNS spoofing, MItM attack, malicious browser plugins, etc):

- Scriptless XSS like CSSAR, SVG-keylogger
- Script XSS like "DOM based XSS", "Dangling markup attacks", PRSSI, "Client side prototype pollution" - [reCaptcha Google still vulnerable](https://csplite.com/csp/test317/).
- various techniques for bypassing CSPs, for example by using the browser cache if page is lodade from cache, the HTTP headers are nor restored.

There are so many XSS attack vectors that it is impossible to describe them all in one article. But Google will help you, just ask it.